# UI from CreateDialog question

Tags: dialog-window

I'm trying to create a dialog box, from which a user can input one or more responses. Here's my code:

`CreateDialog[{"foo",Table[InputField[With[{i = i}, Dynamic[a[i]]], {i, 1, 4}],  Grid[{{DefaultButton[], CancelButton[]}}]}];`

I'd like the fields to appear blank, until the user inputs something. Currently, when executed, all fields are filled with `a[1]`, `a[2]`, etc.

Comment: You could just initialize each of the a[i] to Null before calling CreateDialog. You might also want to look into FormControl and the various related Form* functions. It might give you a cleaner way to specify your dialog and retrieve the inputs.

Comment: Use ``Initialization`` inside ``Dynamic``: ``Dynamic[a[i], Initialization -> (a[_] := Null)]``